# Node-Webkit : Framless to Frame window

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

Is there a way to convert a framless window(for splash) to window with frame(for main application) in node `webkit`? I do not find any reference [here](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/window).

I am try to achieve above in following way:

1. Opening index.html in `mainWindow` and then hide it to open `frameless` `splashWindow`.
2. Initialization completes(initial data for app start up).
3. Hide `splashWindow` and show the `mainWindow` opened in Point 1.

With this approach, multiple process are seen in Task Manager. After packaging, above behavior is hard to achieve as both `mainWindow` and `splashWindow` open as same time.

To counter the above issue, I want to show splash window in `framless` window and then convert it to window with frame(for title and minimize, close and maximize).

Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Done lot of research to convert frameless window to frame window, but could not achieve with native support. My solution was not to use native toolbar and frame. [Created own toolbar and window controls](https://nodehead.com/node-webkit-custom-window-controls-26/) which I controlled as I wanted.